# Perl Socket Program

Tags: perl, sockets, network-programming

I am new to Perl and socket programming and this is what I try to implement, so if script is not able to connect to IP 192.168.0.100 and Port 5000,it trigger an email based on subemail sub-routine.  I am assuming non zero exit code means failure but I am reading some docs and there its mentioned in Perl if socket is not established it return undef value, so I try to match ($? == undef) as well as ($? != 0) as mentioned below, but its not working.  I don't know how to match the exit status so that it will trigger an email, any help is appreciated http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=398525

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use IO::Socket::INET;
$| = 1;
my ($socket,$client_socket);

$socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
    PeerHost => '192.168.0.100',
    PeerPort => '5000',
    Proto    => 'tcp',
) or die "ERROR in Socket Creation : $!\n";

 eval { my $size = $socket->send("Hello"); };
 if ((my $size > 0) || $@) {
 &send_email;
 }

sub subemail
{
my $subject = "ERROR in Socket Creation";
my $body = "\n Check if the logstash server is up \n\n";
my $smtp_server = $ENV{"ET_SMTP_SERVER"};
my ($from, $to) = ("test\@example.com", "testing\@example.com");

 unless ( defined( $smtp_server ) )
 {
  $smtp_server = 'mailhost.example.com';
  }

  my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new( $smtp_server );

  $smtp->mail($from);
  $smtp->to($to);
  $smtp->data();

  $smtp->datasend( 'To: ' . $to . "\n" );
  $smtp->datasend( 'From: ' . $from . "\n" );
  $smtp->datasend( 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n" );

  $smtp->datasend( "\n" );
  $smtp->datasend( $body );
  $smtp->datasend( "\n" );
  $smtp->dataend();
  $smtp->quit;
  }
```

Comment: Does your actual code have that Unicode close-quote on the `die`, or is that an artifact of posting?

Comment: @JimDavis: Thanks Jim for your reply,Actual code also has this Uni-code close quote.

Comment: Does changing it to a real `"` help?

Comment: @JimDavis: Sorry for the confusion that is due to posting..It's " ..

Answer (score 0):

The return it's referring to is probably from `new` itself.  So you'd check:

```
subemail() if not defined $socket;
```